# Change GMSCameraPosition zoom (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to change GMSCameraPosition' zoom programmatically (Google Maps iOS SDK).

I tried to change:

```
mapView.Camera.Zoom=11;
```

but it's a "read-only" property and "setZoom:" does not exist.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is different way to do that.

You can use `-animateToZoom:` on your GMSMapView, or you can create a `GMSCameraPosition` and set the coordinate and zoom level and then use `-animateToCameraPosition:` or create a `GMSCameraUpdate` and then use `-animateWithCameraUpdate:`

```
GMSCameraPosition *cameraPosition = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:latitude
                                                                longitude:longitude
                                                                     zoom:11.0];

[self.mapView animateToCameraPosition:cameraPosition];
```

or

```
GMSCameraUpdate *update = [GMSCameraUpdate zoomTo:11.0];
[self.mapView animateWithCameraUpdate:update];
```

or

```
[self.mapView animateToZoom:11.0];
```

Hope it helps.